# associatedType in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, swift-protocols, associated-types

I'm a beginner in Objective-C.

In Swift, we can use `associatedType` for making protocols generic. Is there any similar API like `associatedType` in Objective-C?

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot use associatedTypes in Objective-C. There's no similar concept in Objective-C either.